# Overhead lights in apartmenet units flicker and eventually goes off...what is the cause and fix?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I live in an apartment building with 4 units. All units are experiencing this weird problem.
Two nights ago the overhead lights started to flicker and then eventually went off. The outlets in all rooms still work!

What could be happening? All 4 units have their own main breaker box. It's strange to me that all overhead lights (in a all 4 units) are behaving strangely.

Tonight...the same thing happened...we were eating dinner and then all of a sudden the lights started to flicker and then they all went off.

Comment: The Lights and the Plugs(outlets) will be on two separate circuits, I assume all four units are supplied by the same Distribution Box? How do the lights go back on?  does a trip switch need to be reset?

Comment: What type of lights are these? is there any "automatic" functionality to them (e.g. motion sensors, timers)? I'm wondering if they may be on a commercial-style lighting control system.